# how to make a delay for few seconds on text to speech in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it posible to make a delay between two phrases using javascript? Others says that "!" can make a delay, but i was looking for other way. I tried `<silence msec="5000" />` but TTS reads it also. The message have to delay for 5-10 seconds every loop from the database. So how i can make a delay for few seconds?

```
//data = database on spreadsheet
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
        var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
        msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
        msg.voiceURI = 'native';
        msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
        msg.rate = 0.8; // 0.1 to 10
        msg.pitch = 0; //0 to 2
        msg.lang = 'en-US';

    var text = "";
    for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
      text = text + " " + data[i][0] + " " + data[i][1] + '! <silence msec="5000" />';
    }
    msg.text = text;
    msg.onend = function(e) {
      console.log('Finished in ' + event.elapsedTime + ' seconds.');
    };
    speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, so we can help.

Comment: So what's the problem with `!`?

Comment: I cannot make a delay for every 3 seconds or how many seconds i want between two  phrase/sentence.

Comment: what about `setTimeout(function(){}, 3000);` ?